# Tracking mouse cursor in QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using the `mouseMoveEvent` to track the position of the mouse cursor in a simple QT app. My problem is that I want the `mouseMoveEvent` to fire only when the cursor is in a 400x400 `QWidget`. Right now it is firing no matter where the mouse is. Here is my code...

```
void IPA2::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event) {
     cout << event->x() << endl;
     cout << event->y() << endl;
}
```

`IPA2` is the name of my class. The ui was created in designer mode.

Comment: simply use mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()) and compare it with event->pos() value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may just perform a check here like `if (x,y in range) do_something`.

Another way would be to create a fake widget with 400x400 dimensions and reimplement it's *mouse event.*

The third (probably an overkill) is to use *event filters* (see [**here**](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/eventsandfilters.html)).

**Update:**

You can't just "easily" handle the mouse events using the Qt Designer. Each `.ui` scheme is almost always paired up with the corresponding *implementation* for that scheme. This is where your handling should be done.

*Qt Designer is great for automatic signal-slot handling, but `mouseMoveEvent` is an `event` and has nothing to do with the slot system.*

I would say how would I implement this and you can choose (see the three possible ways before).

I would create some `DummyWidget`, which would have a 400x400 dimensions and custom virtual `mouseMoveEvent` method, which would actually handle the mouse movement.

In the constructor of my main window (which also does the `.ui-based` construction) I would say something like

```
dummy_widget_ = new DummyWidget(...);
// `dummy_widget_` is a private `DummyWidget*` member of the main window
```

and then probably would reposition it *somewhere*.

That's it - now when my main window is created, a dummy widget is added to it and every mouse movement at that widget is handled (because we've provided custom implementation).

*Another moment, which is related to mouse events only:* http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop

Comment: the x,y is giving me the global positions though. So the numbers are incorrect. I want the position to be referenced from the QWidget.

Comment: Still gives me global position. I think the problem is that the mainwindow is receiving the event, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I think you're doing something unobvious. If you have a widget has a `mouseMoveEvent` function reimplemented, it becomes the default event handler, and the event can't go UP to the main widget. You simply handle it in your local widget (which has 400x400 dimensions). *In that case `pos()` would give you the **relative** position to that widget.*

Comment: Just to mention - http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq11-events.html#acceptorignore - reimplemented event handlers automatically call `accept()` so that the event doesn't traverse to their parents.

Comment: The problem I think lies in the fact that I used the designer to design the ui. So I'm not putting the `mouseMoveEvent` on the actual `QWidget`... I'm putting it on the entire ui (IPA2 is the ui). I cannot figure out for the life of me how to make the mouseMoveEvent access an individual component of the ui.